# render :json => @model with :includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to export data from models via json. I overwrote the `as_json` method in my user model:

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(:only => [:email], :include => :avatar)
end
```

I also have an avatar model, whose `as_json` method I also overwrote.

If I use the `:include` option to add the avatar model, all properties of the avatar model are shown. Any ideas to to let the second model also use the `as_json` method?

Comment: Why do you averwrite the method? I like to use https://github.com/nesquena/rabl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just being explicit about it?

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(:only => [:email]).merge(avatar: avatar.as_json)
end
```